# How to create a ContactsContract.Directory provider and call it in Incoming/outgoing call?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, contactscontract

I'm creating a ContactsContrat.Directory in my android app. That I want to do is: In incoming/outgoing call, the Android dialer do a query to my custom directory that I've registered.

This is the resource that I've read to do it: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Directory.html

This is my code in the AndroidManifest:

```
 <provider
            android:name=".CustomContactProvider"
            android:authorities="com.myapp.CustomContactProvider"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:multiprocess="true"
            android:readPermission="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"
            android:writePermission="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.content.ContactDirectory"
                android:value="true" />
 </provider>
```

According with the android developer resource

> "Custom Directories are discovered by the Contacts Provider following
>   this procedure: It finds all installed content providers with meta
>   data identifying them as directory providers in AndroidManifest.xml:
>    This tag should be placed inside the
>   corresponding content provider declaration."

with the meta-data should be working and do a call to my custom provider every time that the Contacts Provider is call it, but it doesn't work when I do a call or I open the contacts in my phone.

Any suggestion or idea of how to can do this?

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution? I'm digging for the same thing and I think what we want to achieve is not possible.

Comment: Hi, no, I didn't find any solution for this.... I think that is not possible, at least, at the moment...

Comment: Hi, I came across https://simplenexus.dev/2019/08/27/android-caller-id.html. It might help.

Comment: Yes, I posted an answer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57733654/8226956)