# Are Directory Contacts removed in Android 11+?

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, android-11, android-12

I'm working on a contact directory integration. I know that I had this feature on an older phone and want to integrate this feature for my own app. Technical is my question similar to [Provide the caller id for incoming call from my own app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48870782/995926) just that I want to support modern devices with Android 11+. On my Android 12 device my content provider is initialized and can be queried from my own code. However the phone app does not invoke my content provider.

Since I am absolutely sure that this feature has worked in the past. I used the emulator with the result that the app works fine with the API versions 27 and 29, but not with 30. Do you know an API change or was that feature silently dropped for privacy?

I talked with the Google Support and they told me that this feature would only work with work profiles in the context of the cooperate contacts from Google Work Accounts. Is that a general restriction or just something related with Google Accounts?

I made some deeper research and found the class [`ContactDirectoryManager`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/ContactsProvider/+/master/src/com/android/providers/contacts/ContactDirectoryManager.java). I modified the code so far that I was able to execute the `onPackageChanged()` method which detected my content provider correctly as expected. What am I doing wrong?

If you want some sample code check this repo: [simplecallerid](https://github.com/SimpleNexus/simplecallerid)

Bonus question: Does that only work on Stock Android? I found a feature request for Samsung devices [on their frensh community page](https://eu.community.samsung.com/t5/applications-mobiles-services/request-contactdirectory-providers-in-samsung-phone-app/td-p/4742886). It seems that this is not supported there.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I too was using "android.content.ContactDirectory". I can confirm that the AOSP dialer does not seem to invoke "phone_lookup" which was the only part my app was supporting.

I can query ContactsContract.Directory.ENTERPRISE_CONTENT_URI and see my app being registered and even make requests to it. But AOSP dialer no longer queries it.

Perhaps performance was reason for it to stop querying other directories.

I suppose we can dig in to AOSP commit history to find the change but who has the time?

Comment: Thank you for remember me that I asked that. It is still possible, even on Android 13 (I have still installed my sample app). I'll try to find some time to answer it. I wrote a sample app which I need to find again first.